# Scraping Indeed with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm unfamiliar with html and web scraping with beautiful soup. I'm trying to retrieve Job titles, salaries, location and company name from various indeed job postings. This is my code so far:

```
URL = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist+%2420%2C000&l=New+York&start=10"
import urllib2
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())
resultcol = soup.find_all(id = 'resultsCol')
company = soup.findAll('span', attrs={"class":"company"})
jobs = (soup.find_all({'class': " row result"}))
```

though I have the commands to find jobs and company, I can't get the contents. I'm aware there's a contents command, but none of my variables so far have that attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I seach `div` with one job all elements and then I search elements inside this `div`

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist+%2420%2C000&l=New+York&start=10"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read(), 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-tn-component': 'organicJob'})

for x in results:
    company = x.find('span', attrs={"itemprop":"name"})
    print 'company:', company.text.strip()

    job = x.find('a', attrs={'data-tn-element': "jobTitle"})
    print 'job:', job.text.strip()

    salary = x.find('nobr')
    if salary:
        print 'salary:', salary.text.strip()

    print '----------'
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to scrape salaries? Here's how it's nested:
 '<tr>
           <td class="snip">
            <nobr>
             $88,305 - $146,570 a year
            </nobr>
'

Comment: I tried too - it works. But most jobs don't have salary so you have to use `if` to check it.

Answer (score 2):

updated @furas example, for python3:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist+%2420%2C000&l=New+York&start=10"    

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(URL).read(), 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-tn-component': 'organicJob'})

for x in results:

    company = x.find('span', attrs={"class":"company"})
    if company:
        print('company:', company.text.strip() )

    job = x.find('a', attrs={'data-tn-element': "jobTitle"})
    if job:
        print('job:', job.text.strip())

    salary = x.find('nobr')
    if salary:
        print('salary:', salary.text.strip())

    print ('----------')
```